# Gestures are not working when CAShapeLayer is added as a SubLayer of UIView in Xamarin.Ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

What I have tried is

```
      CAShapeLayer shapeLayer = new CAShapeLayer();

      shapeLayer.Path = new CGPath();

      shapeLayer.Path.AddLines(new CGPoint [] { startingPoint, endingPoint});

      shapeLayer.StrokeColor = UIColor.Blue.CGColor;

      shapeLayer.LineWidth = (System.nfloat)3.0;

      shapeLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
```

In the above code I have draw a line using starting point and endingPoint. Now these shapeLayer is added as Sublayer of another view.

```
      var view = new UIView();

      view.Layer.AddSubLayer(shapeLayer);
```

Now these view as added as a subview of another view i.e CanvasView. In these we are implement the all gestures functionality.

```
      CanvasView canvasDrawLine = new CanvasView(subView);
```

here is the canvasView :

```
      Public Class CanvasView : UIView
     {
        public CanvasView(drawline)
        {
           this.AddSubview(drawLine);

           setUpGestures();
        }
     }
```

I have added all type of gestures in 'setUpGestures' method. Now these CanvasView is added as a subview of 'scrollView'. scrollView is the superView.

```
       scrollView.AddSubview(canvasDrawLine );
```

What my problem is after line draw, gestures are not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is frame of your subview? Check it with debugging. If not correct assign correct frame to view after adding to superview.

Comment: Initially i am not added any frame, then after I have added frame to the Subview.

Comment: Did you check at runtime by debugging if its frame is same as Whats its showing?

Comment: add this canvasDrawLine.ClipsToBounds = true; and drawLine.ClipsToBounds = true;

Comment: I have added frame to the subview also gestures are not working.

Comment: Thanks, I will add what you suggest and ping you what happen.

Comment: After adding what you suggest, even line also not appear.I don't know what the exact problem.

Comment: Problem is your views frames are not set properly.   let me add detail in answer.

Comment: Sorry, what type of details you want for getting clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set frame of your view when you add it to superview with AddSubview. 
When you add view to superview, It may display its content which  is outside its bounds but Because its frame is (0,0) -- It don't have any touch area. and thats why you cant get gesture events.

1) Add canvasDrawLine.ClipsToBounds = true and drawLine.ClipsToBounds = true.
This is to check what is bounds for your subviews:
after doing this, It will display data only inside the bounds of view. So if frame of view is 0,0-- it will not display any data. ClipsToBounds  Clip the view out side its bounds (Frames width and height)..

2) Assign proper frame to Both views.

```
CanvasDrawLine.frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100); //edit it according to your requirement,

drawLine.frame =  new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100); //edit it according to your requirement,
```

For testing you can use above frame and verify gestures. You can assign proper frame according to your requirement then.

Comment: Thank you very much. it's working fine now but i face some other issue.i.e how can i give exact draw line frame to the view. if give some extra width than draw line, getstures are working out of the draw line also.

Comment: CanvasDrawLine.frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 500, 1500);
drawLine.frame =  new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 500, 1500);

Comment: I have gave these frames and apply the pan gestures, even out of the draw line also pan gestures are working and move the draw line.please suggest any idea.

Comment: To restrict the gestures working on draw line area itself.

Comment: You have startPoint and endPoint-- Create from from that. Starpoint.x, startPoint.y  = origin and Endpoint.x-startpoint.x =width and Endpoint.y-startpoint.y = height..  you may add some spacing

Comment: I think you should ask New Question for this problem.